# MariaDB on CentOS 7 refuses to read some updated variables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, config, centos7

I'm trying to change `max_connections` and `open_files_limit` for MariaDB version 5.5.60 on CentOS 7.
Since there could be multiple my.cnf files, I used `mysql --help --verbose` to get possible locations. Here's the output:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

The /etc/mysql/my.cnf doesn't exist and .my.cnf isn't in my user directory, /root/ or mysql user's directory (which doesn't exist to begin with).
So I'm left with /etc/my.cnf. This is what it looks like:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
max_connections = 5000
open_files_limit = 10240

# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

The /etc/my.cnf.d from the last line contains server.cnf, which includes these two lines:

```
[server]
max_connections=5000
open_files_limit=10240
```

However, when I run `systemctl restart mariadb`, only the max_connections is changed, but I just can't get it to read the new value of `open_files_limit`.
It keeps doing this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| open_files_limit | 1024  |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Do you have any idea why it's doing this and how I could get the server to read the new value of `open_files_limit`?

Thank you in advance

Sasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of open_file_limits variable can't be higher than your system limits.

Check output of `ulimit -n` and change your system configuration. Preferable assign these limits not system wide, but for the user under which MariaDB server is running.